# Register kubectl exec command while new Pod creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Dockerfile which copies an installer to the container and the default command specified in Dockerfile is `/usr/sbin/init`, since I need to run certain services. Once the container is created via `kubectl create -f server-rc.yml` command, I am running a kubectl exec command in interactive mode to run that installer and provide inputs automatically via node.js script, the command goes like this `kubectl exec $container -i -t -- bash -c "node install.js"`(this runs the installer and automatically provides inputs via stdin), which starts my custom service on the pods.

Everything is fine till now. Now let's says out of 2 pods, one pod dies and a new one spawns up. Now, how can I ensure that these interactive commands that I had initially run on the pods gets run on the newly generated pods as well? I am not sure if using `command` and `args` in the spec would work since they all work in non interactive mode. Any thoughts on how to get this resolved would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Dockerfile(partial code):

```
FROM centos:7

ENV container docker

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all

VOLUME [ “/sys/fs/cgroup” ]

RUN yum -y install nodejs npm && npm install progress

RUN mkdir -p /tmp

COPY ./install.js /tmp

COPY ./test.bin /tmp/

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

The node.js script opens up `test.bin` via `child_process.spawn` and then listens on `process.stdout.on` and based on what is received on stdout, provides inputs via `process.stdin.write`.

Thanks.

Comment: Would an init container (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) be helpful? (installing the node app in a volume, that owould then be mounted by the container)

Comment: You can add your input value in the configmap and mount the configmap as file in your pod. this will remove the interaction part

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by interactive. If this means the script needs human interaction, you cannot automate this (since you need somebody who does that).

Since Kubernetes Pods can die anytime you should make the script non-interactive and extend the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)/[command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), so it does the `node install.js` before starting the actual server. One example is the official Docker image for MySQL, which [defines an entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/86431f073b3d2f963d21e33cb8943f0bdcdf143d/8.0/Dockerfile#L67) and does some preconfiguration before [actually starting the server](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/86431f073b3d2f963d21e33cb8943f0bdcdf143d/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh).

It's hard to be more precise, since we don't have the Dockerfile or the `install.js` script.

**Edit** It would be even better if the `install.js` would run inside the Dockerfile, since this would speed up the start and make the server code immutable.

Comment: I just updated my question with the Dockerfile and what the install.js script does. Yes, the script needs human interaction but I am simulating it in my install.js file to listen on `process.stdout.on` and then writing the inputs to `process.stdin.write`.

Comment: In this case you just need to write a script where you do this first and which executes `/usr/sbin/init` in the end. This script needs to replace `CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Executing `/usr/sbin/init` via shell script doesn't seem to work for me. Getting the below error `Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn` . For now, I am using CMD as `/usr/sbin/init` itself but registering a cron job to run the script a minute later via crontab. Kinda hacky solution.

Comment: You could try `exec /usr/sbin/init`. Besides that, your `CMD` looks like a heavy init process which is a bad practice with Docker. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern).